# how to get http status code in volley library when response in success.?

Tags: android, android-volley, status

I know its a repetitive question, but still. Can any one provide me a solution or workaround to get status code returned with the response when we make a network rest api call?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271686/how-to-get-status-code-in-successful-response-volley-android) provided a work around. But I didn't understood. Can any one explain me in a better way the solution.?

The rest api returns many success status code like 201,204 and many server errors.

I want to check status code before proceeding and have to make decision accordingly.

This is my existing code.

on a button click

```
RequestQueue queue;
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
final String[] token = new String[1];
String status;
String url = "http://myapiurl";
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                // want to get status code here
                token[0] = response.getString("message");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),token[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // error
            Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    }
);
queue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get status code in successful response Volley Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271686/how-to-get-status-code-in-successful-response-volley-android)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: previously didn't answer the question at all.

It seems nontrivial to do this while using the clean Listener interfaces, but it's also possible to [implement this as a custom request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) (the examples specifically show parsing JSON). You can look at the [JsonObjectRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java) and [JsonRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonRequest.java) sources for inspiration.

You should end up with something like this (heavily inspired by JsonObjectRequest):

```
Request<JSONObject> request = new Request<JSONObject>() {
  @Override
  protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
      String jsonString = new String(
        response.data,
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
      // can access response.statusCode here
      // ...
      return Response.success(obj, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
      return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If the request is success will the success status code appear in ErrorListner.?

Comment: I did miss the OP's original question completely. Sorry,